# PyTesseract - installation issue

Tags: python-tesseract

while trying to get my script to run, I am having issues with Pytesseract.
I have installed through pip and installed the exe file.
However, when trying to run following simplified code:

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(rotated_image)
```

I am constantly plagued by following error code:

```
OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

I have admin rights over my laptop but am not the main account.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Run the terminal or the IDE as administrator.

[image]

Then the error about `OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation` should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

I can just use this code to use `tesseract` without setting the path.

```
import pytesseract

result = pytesseract.image_to_string("./important/aaa.jpg")
print(result)
```

Because I add `tesseract` folder to System PATH.

You have installed `tesseract` in your `C:\Program Files (x86)`.This directory can not be access easily without Administrator permission.

So now,If you don't want to run this code as Administrator,you can just

**add the folder of `tesseract` to your system PATH.**

Did you get it?